# concatenate a string to input variable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build shiny app which will download and plot stock data based on input requirements using quantmod package.In shiny the input is taken as stock name for ex: TCS . However the stock symbol taken by quantmod is TCS.NS .

```
ui <-fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Stock Analysis"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = "symbols",label="Enter Stock Name",
                        choices="TCS","MARUTI","HDFCBANK"),
            dateInput("start_date",h3("start Date"),value="2019-01-01"),
            dateInput("end_date",h3("End Date"),value="2019-09-01"),
......
```

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$plot=renderPlot({

        input$symbols <-paste0(input$symbols,".NS",sep="")

 data=getSymbols(input$symbols,from=input$start_date,to=input$end_date,auto.assign=FALSE)
         data=na.omit(data)
         chartSeries(data)
        })
```

```
Warning: Error in $<-.reactivevalues: Attempted to assign value to a read-only reactivevalues object
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
input$symbols <-paste0(input$symbols,".NS",sep="")
```

can be changed as it is assigning to a read-only reactive object.  Instead, create a new object identifier and read it (Also with `paste0`, we don't need the `sep = ""`)

```
newObj <-paste0(input$symbols,".NS")
data <- getSymbols(newObj,from=input$start_date,to=input$end_date,auto.assign=FALSE)
```